# Select multiple values from one table based on values in another

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'd like to select all the rows in the `plot` table where it exists in `watchlist`. For instance, with the example I've uploaded to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c54c01/7), I should be able to return rows `3`, `5` and `8` in `plot` with the query, because they exist in `watchlist`. The problem is, I am not sure how to go about it. Any ideas?

This is what I've done so far:

```
SELECT id, p_id, area, jobs from plot WHERE code="SA" AND p_id="3";
```

But only selects one row, but I understand that it would require a subquery of some sort i.e. replacing `WHERE code="SA" AND p_id="3";` with a reference to the **watchlist** table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN` to check this:

```
SELECT t1.id
     , t1.p_id
     , t1.area
     , t1.jobs 
FROM plot t1 
JOIN watchlist t2 ON t1.p_id = t2.p_id
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c54c01/15)

Answer (score 0):

**Returns ROWS 3, 5, and 8**

```
SELECT *
FROM plot, watchlist
WHERE plot.p_id = watchlist.p_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the other responses - there are multiple solutions, so I will add a `SUBQUERY` solution since you mentioned subquery.

```
SELECT id, p_id, area, jobs 
  FROM plot 
  WHERE p_id in
  (SELECT p_id
      FROM watchlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this it will work :**

```
SELECT t1.* from `plot` t1 JOIN `watchlist` t2 ON t1.`P_ID`=t2.`P_ID`
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c54c01/23)